# Capturing repeated named groups

Tags: java, regex

I have following string `class teacher john smith pupils max power al bundy`
How can I capture all pupils of Mr. Smith's class with named groups?

I created this regex
`(?:^class teacher )(?<teacher>(?<first>\w+) (?<last>\w+)) pupils (?<pupil>(?<pfirst>\w+) (?<plast>\w+) )+`
but it's leaving out the pupil `al bundy`.

Tested it on Java and [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't repeat a capture group because the last matched value will overwrite the previous.

A way to solve this kind of problem consists to use the `find` method with the `\G` anchor to obtain consecutive matches:

```
(?:\G(?!\A) |\Aclass teacher (?<teacher>(?<first>\w+) (?<last>\w+)) pupils )(?<pupil>(?<pfirst>\w+) (?<plast>\w+))
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/vH9kR7/1)

*(Obviously an other way is to capture all pupils in one group and to split it after)*

Comment: Thx. And yes, the other way is a valid option. Since I'm searching for an **easy**, declarative way to extract data from strings (shell commands).